# Как узнать расширение файла на python

Tags: python, файлы, download

у меня есть скрипт на загрузку файла через url, как мне ужнать шасширение файла по url,
пример url: https://cdn.upload.systems/uploads/Ns.k9sV6K.png, там есть 2 точки, поэтому не вариант пытаться узнать расширение после этой точке

Comment: после какой "этой"? После первой точки с конца вполне себе расширение и очень даже вариант

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно подойдёт такой вариант.

```
url = 'https://cdn.upload.systems/uploads/Ns.k9sV6K.png'
extension = url.split('.')[-1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Вариант #1

```
extension = os.path.splitext(url)[1]
```

Вариант #2

```
extension = pathlib.Path(url).suffix
```

Использование простого метода `split('.')` может вернуть не совсем то, что ожидалось в случае если сам файл не имеет расширения, но точка есть в пути (в данном случае она как минимум есть в доменном имени).

Answer (score 0):

Альтернативное решение:

```
ext = url.rsplit('.', 1)[-1]
```